# Transfer Btc to bcc problem

Tags: bitcoin-cash, cross-chain-recovery

I have transfer bitcoin from zepay to BCC with the bcc receive address . BUT the BCC is not updated with the transfered amount.
Is there any way to track the transaction??

Answer (score 0):

```
If you have sent BTC to a BCH address your coins are lost.

BCH is not bitcoin it is an altcoin with it's own blockchain, it has been deliberately created by its creators to deceive people into thinking it is bitcoin.
```

This is not true, and is only the case if you do not own the private keys for the wallet you sent your BTC to.

BTC / BCH adresses are exactly the same.

Unless you've sent them to an exchange which is not willing to co-operate to get your funds back, you should be fine. Simply open up a support ticket, and ask them to get your BTC back you sent to their BCC adress.

Answer (score 0):

> This is not true, and is only the case if you do not own the private keys for the wallet you sent your BTC to.
>
> BTC / BCH adresses are exactly the same.

This is complete mis-information, yes BTC and BCH address are the same address format but they exist on a completely separate blockchain.

Unless you own the corresponding private key on the other chain there is little chance of receiving the coins back, since it is almost impossible to generate the address you sent to.

> Unless you've sent them to an exchange which is not willing to co-operate to get your funds back, you should be fine. Simply open up a support ticket, and ask them to get your BTC back you sent to their BCC address.

Asking an exchange to refund the lost coins my work, but they are under no obligation to do so, as the exchange have not received the coins so this is not a solid answer on how to return them

Comment: You've left out context of the answer i quoted (which has since been deleted?). Ofcourse, if you don't own the private key for the bitcoin adress, you can't possibly own the private key for the same bitcoin cash adresss.